# Sum values based on word in line in bash

Tags: bash

I have a script which outputs a number followed by a space and then a letter, e.g.:

```
2685 R
2435 M
984 D
924 A
353 R
291 A
593 D
577 A
476 R
769 M
629 R
179 D
```

Is there an easy way to sum the numbers based on the letter/word after the number? I would like this to be the output:

```
1792 A
1756 D
3204 M
4143 R
```

I have tried `sort`, `awk` and `sed` combinations but can't find a nice solution to sum.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{a[$2]+=$1} END{for(i in a){print a[i],i}}' Input_file
```

In case you want to sort it as per 2nd field then append `| sort -k2` to above code too.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I added ``| sort -nr`` at the end to sort by highest number first. ``bash script.sh | awk '{a[$2]+=$1} END{for(i in a){print a[i], i}}' | sort -nr``